# htaccess is redirecting all post data 302 error

Tags: php, .htaccess

Heres my .htaccess code snippet

```
RewriteEngine on 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*)?$ $1.php?causecode=$2
```

heres my from

```
<form action="http://localhost/Nirav/create-cause-page/" method="POST">
```

Whenever I am printing the post data it shows null. I checked apache logs and saw 302 error.

Kindly help

Comment: You're forcing a client-side 302 redirect. That makes the client request the new url via GET, which means your POST data is lost.

Comment: 302 is not an error code - w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know htaccess too much. Can you please tell me where I am making the redirection. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should state what you are trying to achieve, not what you're trying to avoid.

Comment: Whenever I am submitting the form. My POST data is being lost.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2012:20:16:05 +0530] "POST /Nirav/create-cause-page/ HTTP/1.1" 302 2508 "http://localhost/Nirav/create-cause-page/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2"
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2012:20:16:05 +0530] "GET /Nirav/create-cause-page/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2383 "http://localhost/Nirav/create-cause-page/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2"

Comment: Try removing everything from your .htaccess file and see if it works OK.

Comment: From what I understand your form submission is being redirected to the same page via a 302 redirect but your POST data is lost during the process. Try my advice above.

Comment: I removed all the data from htaccess it worked but I want seo friendly URL for that I must use htaccess ..

Comment: I would suggest checking what is generating 302 code -- mod_rewrite/Apache or your php script. Those rules will not generate that. Try enabling rewrite debugging/logging (on max level, of course) to see what result mod_rewrite will produce. So far I think it is your PHP code who generates 302 response.

Comment: My guess is that the 302 is generated by the php script. Nothing in your htaccess should generate a 302 (assuming you posted the entire htaccess content).